# How Can I send a googlespreadsheet as xls or xlsx attachment email

Tags: google-sheets

4 years ago I used a script that can attach the googlespreadsheet as xlsx but now is not working any more because the funtion is not longer supported.

Anyone know how can I atth. the googlespreadsheet as xlsx?

Answer (score 1):

This script sends an e-mail with an Excel file exported from spreadsheet as an attachment file.
For this script, it is necessary to input an access token, a sheet ID, an excel file name and an e-mail address. And Drive API is "ON" at [the API Console](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library). The flow for retrieving access token is https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios.

Scopes are `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file`.

```
function excelSender() {
  var sheetID = [Sheet ID];
  var xlsxName = [Excel file name];
  var params = {
    "headers" : {Authorization: "Bearer [Retrieved AccessToken]"},
    "muteHttpExceptions" : true
  };
  var dUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/" + sheetID + "/export?mimeType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
  var xlsxlFile = UrlFetchApp.fetch(dUrl, params).getBlob().setName(xlsxName);
  MailApp.sendEmail({
    to: [Mail address],
    subject: "sample subject",
    body: "sample body",
    attachments: [xlsxlFile]
  });
}
```

[image]

I could get an e-mail with an excel file.

Comment: Hi, at the moment is not working. I enable Drive API, Sheet API & GMAIL API, but didn't work. Is sending the email but the attach didn't have the format and extention is not possible open.

Comment: Can I ask you about the error and your script which you modified? For personal information, please fill by "#####". When I run this, it works fine. For this script, you don't need some preparations which are Drive API and others. When you run this, authentication dialog appears. When you push the button on the dialog, this script works. Please create new GAS project and paste this script, and try again.

Comment: You said is working for you right now? not appear error the sheet is attach in the email appear name without extention.

Comment: The problem is your code add a link for sheet, and only work with gmail account. I need to download the spreadsheet and attach as XLSX in an email sent out of gmail

Comment: As a result, it seems that "getOAuthToken()" is unstable. In my google account, although it had worked fine when it created new GAS project, now it doesn't work. (Isn't Access token refreshed?) I apologize that I cannot find the reason. But it was found that the access token manually retrieved can be used for downloading. So I modified the sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: 1. Active Drive Api from Tool in console.<br>
2. Active the scope drive + drive.file in googleexplorer api<br>
3. I don't where i can get token id<br>
4. I think i missed some part o configuration
5. What I need to be put here [Retrieved AccessToken]

Comment: Do you enable V2 or V3 drive Api?, because un explorer api appear 2 version, I suppose is V2

Comment: I could know that you use V2, just now. When you use V2, please change ``https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/`` to https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/``.

Comment: 1. Inset sheet id, Name
2. Resources > Advance service google > Active Drive API V2
3. Ingress to Console for the Proyect ID > Go to Credential > Creat a Aouth for Other I don't what exacly type need to be selected.
The system give me Client ID and Secret ID
4. Insert Client ID in the line where said [Retrieved AccessToken], 
5. Ingress to google explorer api, check and enlable Drive Api V2
6. url googleapis.com/drive/v2/files return error

Comment: Error {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceededUnreg",
    "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://code.google.com/apis/console"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded. Continued use requires signup."
 }
}

Comment: From your errors, it seems that the accesstoken cannot be retrieved. But it is also necessary to confirm your modified script. So can I see your script? I will check it while you retrieve accesstoken by checking at developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#scenarios and developers.google.com/identity/protocols/ When you add your script, please add it to your question using EDIT button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google Drive API to achieve your goal.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export

Comment: I try to use many time but is too dificult to my knowlege right now... My spreasheet example is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cfZ1zQ5lokrC0DN6FMgMCmM5WCCBL9trHxpJlN-aRiY/edit#gid=0